# Epson ePOS SDK for Android (Xamarin) missing constants

Tags: java, c#, xamarin.android, epos

We are trying to updgrade the SDK of epson, which is deprecated since a long while.

We were using the old ePOS-Print SDK (com.epson.eposprint) package and we began having problems with it, so we rightly decided to migrate to the current one, Epson ePOS SDK for Android (com.epson.epos2).

We are using Visual Studio Xamarin.

We followed the migration document included in the SDK. Replaced most of the code. But, it seems that either Xamarin has problem the java bindings or something is missing, because almost 90% of the enum values are not available. It's almost near impossible without the enum values to correctly call the methods... For example, we do have some of the enums available (like the BatteryLevelX, TMxx, Pattern*), but that's about it.

We are using Android 8.0

Our javabinding project is configured like that:

```
--JarLibrary
----Jars
-------ePOS2.jar
-------ePOSEasySelect.jar
----libs
------armeabi
--------libepos2.so
--------libeposeasyselect.so
------armeabi-v7a
--------libepos2.so
--------libeposeasyselect.so
```

Project Properties:

Android Class parser: jar2xml
Android codegen target: XAJavaInterop1

Any ideas why this is?

**EDIT :** Solution is to make sure all objects with no visibility keywords in the SDK is fixed with the Metadata.xml Transforms file, this way:

```
<!-- On enlève l'ancienne classe du package qui ne sert plus à rien, juste pour la migration -->
<remove-node path="/api/package[starts-with(@name, 'com.epson.epsonio')]" />

<!-- Need to change the visibility of many ommited classes visibility in jar epos -->
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice']/class[@name='NativeDevice']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice.commbox']/class[@name='NativeCommBox']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice.commbox']/class[@name='NativeCommBoxManager']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice.keyboard']/class[@name='NativeKeyboard']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice.printer']/class[@name='NativePrinter']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice.scanner']/class[@name='NativeScanner']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice.simpleserial']/class[@name='NativeSimpleSerial']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice']/class[@name='DeviceInnerImplement']"
      name="visibility">protected</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice']/class[@name='NativeDevice']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.epos2.printer']/class[@name='CommonPrinter']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.epos2.printer']/class[@name='LogoKeyCode']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.epos2']/class[@name='NativeInitializer']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.epos2']/class[@name='OutputLog']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice.display']/class[@name='NativeDisplay']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice']/class[@name='Device.DeleteDeviceCallbackAdapter']"
      name="visibility">protected</attr>
```

Comment: Just to add to this, I opened the com.epson.epos2 with a java decompiler, and it seems the constants are in the abstract class CommonPrinter, that the Printer class inherits from. But, in the generated c# wrapper class, the printer class inherits only from  global::Java.Lang.Object 

Is it a binding problem?

Comment: if anyone can add this https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5921&scat=61&pcat=52 to a jar xamarin projects and make it build, please advise.

Comment: @nicolas-belly did you get this to work? What is your build action on the `.so` files?

Comment: @JonathanPeel no, we rolled back to the old SDK

Comment: @NicolasBelley : Can you Please tell me with version this SDK works fine? and also provide me that SDK as well as i am unable to download old sdk from Epson

Comment: @KrunalBagadia I'm not sure which one we have, but for using with Xamarin, you cannot clear the 1 major version, so I found a sample on github with the 1.9.0a, I think you should be OK with that: https://github.com/EPSONePOS/ePOS

Comment: @NicolasBelley What is your build action on the .so files? and can you share with me a sample of how to print a receipt ? I keep getting a java.lang.LinkageError

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT :** Solution is to make sure all objects with no visibility keywords in the SDK is fixed with the Metadata.xml Transforms file, this way:

```
<!-- On enlève l'ancienne classe du package qui ne sert plus à rien, juste pour la migration -->
<remove-node path="/api/package[starts-with(@name, 'com.epson.epsonio')]" />

<!-- Need to change the visibility of many ommited classes visibility in jar epos -->
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice']/class[@name='NativeDevice']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice.commbox']/class[@name='NativeCommBox']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice.commbox']/class[@name='NativeCommBoxManager']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice.keyboard']/class[@name='NativeKeyboard']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice.printer']/class[@name='NativePrinter']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice.scanner']/class[@name='NativeScanner']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice.simpleserial']/class[@name='NativeSimpleSerial']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice']/class[@name='DeviceInnerImplement']"
      name="visibility">protected</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice']/class[@name='NativeDevice']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.epos2.printer']/class[@name='CommonPrinter']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.epos2.printer']/class[@name='LogoKeyCode']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.epos2']/class[@name='NativeInitializer']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.epos2']/class[@name='OutputLog']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice.display']/class[@name='NativeDisplay']"
      name="visibility">public</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.eposdevice']/class[@name='Device.DeleteDeviceCallbackAdapter']"
      name="visibility">protected</attr>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still struggling with this, I've found a solution that seems to do the job without re-writing the library.

1. In your solution, create a new "Android Bindings Library (Xamarin)" project.
2. Add the ePOS2.jar (and ePOSEasySelect.jar if needed) file to the "Jars" folder and set the file's build action (in the properties window) to "EmbeddedJar".
3. INSTALL THE OPOS Common Control Objects (CCOs) locally (OPOS_CCOs_1.14.001.msi) from the [Epson ePOS SDK for Android download](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=6349&scat=61&pcat=52).
4. Copy all of the resulting .dll files to your project from step 1. I've used a "lib" folder within it, but you do you.
5. Reference the .dlls from the project.
6. Build.

You should end up with a library you can reference from other projects and make use of the `Com.Epson.Epos2` namespace and all the classes within it.

For reference, most of the useful constants are accessed through the `Com.Epson.Eposdevice namespace`. e.g. `Com.Epson.Eposdevice.Printer.Printer.LangEn`

Note: There is no default `DiscoveryListener` class, so you would need to build your own if you go down that route.

Also worth remembering most Java projects use `camelCaseFormatting` for their method names, so when copy/pasting examples from the documentation (which is woeful), don't forget to change your methods to `TitleCaseFormatting`.

Also, Also: I keep getting an error with `global::Com.Epson.Epos2.Printer.LogoKeyCode` not existing for whatever reason. A temporary solution is to add the following line to the `MetaData.xml` file in the Bindings Library's `Transforms` folder:

```
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.epson.epos2.printer']/class[@name='Printer']/method[@name='getLogoList' and count(parameter)=0]"/>
```

Comment: You can check my edited answer, the changes are less large than previously thought. I'm now correctly using one of the latest versions of the SDK!

Answer (score -1):

The **recommended solution** to this binding problem is to remove the problem element rather than tweak the modifier (non-public to public) in the `Transforms/Metadata.xml` file. More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings#problem-missing-c-types-in-generated-output) from **Microsoft Docs**.

**Example,**

- Remove the entire non-public class from the binding,

  ```
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='android.support.v4.content']/class[@name='AsyncTaskLoader.LoadTask']" />
  ```
- Remove just the non-public method from the binding,

  ```
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='android.support.v4.content']/class[@name='CursorLoader']/method[@name='loadInBackground']" />
  ```

Comment: I'm sorry this will not work because WE NEED some of those enums and methods binded to use in the code, it needs to be made public.