# Printing to POS Printers in Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: java, xamarin, dll, jar, pos

I have an app that is built with XF and I want it to be able to discover POS Printers through LAN, USB and maybe WIFI too, and print receipts with a very simple template. Does anyone have any leads ? there is this ePOS Android SDK :

https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=prod&pcat=3&pid=36

But it's with JAVA.  And I also found this nugget ESC-POS :

https://github.com/lukevp/ESC-POS-.NET

If there is anyone who have any idea on how I should proceed or already done it before I would really really appreciate it.

---

**EDIT**

So I deicided to work with the SDK found on EPSON website. I have 2 files .JAR

- ePOS2.jar
  Compiled Java class file, archived into a jar format file to allow APIs 
  to be used from Java programs.
- ePOSEasySelect.jar
  A Java class file for selecting a printer easily

and some other lib files .so . All I got to do now is find the correct way to use theme in my Xamarin app. so I found this :

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar

can anyone with further experience help me with that please ?

Comment: discovering printers and printing to them are two completely separate issues.  Printing usually requires knowledge about the individual printer and what printing language it supports.

Comment: @Jason Yes it's true, I found that most printers supports the Epson Standard Code so I guess that won't be a very big problem or am I mistaken ? for exemple I guess that most of EPSON printers could be commanded with the same way ?

Comment: I have no idea.  I've only had to work with one specific printer before

Comment: @Jason I see that's great, was it an EPSON printer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was able to creat a .dll file and add it as a reference in my xamarin.android project :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar

Also I had to do some quick tweaking in the metadata file as mentionned in this thread :

[Epson ePOS SDK for Android (Xamarin) missing constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166161/epson-epos-sdk-for-android-xamarin-missing-constants/55285399#55285399)